# Tealium Tags Integration with React Js

Tags: reactjs, tealium

I am trying to integrate Tealium tags with our react.js based project; however, I do not happen to find any documentation regarding this matter? I would be appreciative if anybody could either provide me with some docs or examples as to how can this be done?

Answer (score 7):

## Updated October 2023:

I put together a [Next.js Example Repo](https://github.com/danielbank/react-tealium-example) demonstrating one approach to integrate Tealium into a React application. The salient features are:

### [Store Tealium account info in public environment variables](https://github.com/danielbank/react-tealium-example/blob/main/.env.example#L12-L14)

Tealium account info is in the vendor script url, so it is public information.  With public environment variables, it gets inlined into the JavaScript sent to the browser.

### [Load Tealium script](https://github.com/danielbank/react-tealium-example/blob/main/src/pages/index.tsx#L32-L63)

Tealium script is loaded at the page-level at the end of the page.

### [Store reference to `window.utag` in context](https://github.com/danielbank/react-tealium-example/blob/main/hooks/useUtag.tsx#L49)

The useState and useEffect approach for polling for the utag object on the window could probably be improved. Regardless, the net result is the value changes from an `EmptyUtag` object (that discards calls) to a reference to the `window.utag` global object.

```
<UtagContext.Provider value={utag}>{children}</UtagContext.Provider>
```

### [Wrap App component with a context provider](https://github.com/danielbank/react-tealium-example/blob/main/src/pages/_app.tsx#L7-L9)

The App component is wrapped with `UtagProvider` so that individual page's can use the utag value in their logic.

```
const MyApp: AppType = ({ Component, pageProps }) => {
  return (
    <UtagProvider>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </UtagProvider>
  );
};
```

### [Explicitly handle page views](https://github.com/danielbank/react-tealium-example/blob/main/src/pages/index.tsx#L17-L20)

Page views are handled explicitly in Page-level component useEffect

```
useEffect(() => {
  // Explicitly handle page views
  utag.view({ page_name: "Mens Fashion: View Page" });
}, [utag]);
```

### [Track events at the component-level](https://github.com/danielbank/react-tealium-example/blob/main/components/ShirtsForm.tsx#L16-L22)

```
<input
  name="shirts"
  type="range"
  min="0"
  max="100"
  step="1"
  onChange={(e) => {
    utag.link({
      tealium_event: "Change Quantity",
      product_id: ["12345"],
      product_name: ["Lucky Shirt"],
      product_quantity: [e.target.value],
      product_price: ["12.99"],
    });
  }}
/>
```

---

## Original Answer from 2021

The Tealium Documentation has [a section on Single Page Applications](https://docs.tealium.com/platforms/javascript/single-page-applications/) which is applicable to React.  This answer references that documentation and adds a little from my experience.

### Modify the Tealium Script

Firstly, you need to modify their global script slightly with the following two lines:

```
window.utag_cfg_ovrd = window.utag_cfg_ovrd || {};
window.utag_cfg_ovrd.noview = true;
```

This overrides the automatic page tracking (since there is no page navigation happening in a SPA).  The complete script should look like (modifying the code in the [installation guide](https://docs.tealium.com/platforms/javascript/install/)):

```
<!-- Tealium Universal Data Object -->
<script type="text/javascript">
  var utag_data={
      "page_type"     : "section",
      "site_section"  : "men",
      "page_name"     : "Men's Fashion | Acme Inc.",
      "country_code"  : "US",
      "currency_code" : "USD"};
  window.utag_cfg_ovrd = window.utag_cfg_ovrd || {};
  window.utag_cfg_ovrd.noview = true
</script>

<!-- Tealium Universal Tag -->
<script type="text/javascript">
  (function(a,b,c,d) {
      a='//tags.tiqcdn.com/utag/ACCOUNT/PROFILE/ENVIRONMENT/utag.js';
      b=document;c='script';d=b.createElement(c);d.src=a;
      d.type='text/java'+c;d.async=true;
      a=b.getElementsByTagName(c)[0];a.parentNode.insertBefore(d,a)})();
</script>
```

### Explicitly Handle Views

Since there is no page navigation, you will need to programmatically call `utag.view()` in places where you are doing routing:

```
window.utag.view({ variable1:"VARIABLE1 VALUE", variable2:"VARIABLE2 VALUE", variable3:"VARIABLE3 VALUE" });
```

### Handle the Asynchronous Load of Utag

If you are using the default mode, the utag object is loaded asynchronously and your React code may attempt to call it before it has finished loading.  You should have some logic guarding access until utag has properly loaded.  Below is some example code:

### Provide a Default Utag

```
// If you aren't worried about calling utag before it has loaded (e.g. user interactions)
// This will try to call Tealium but will just drop the event if utag is not loaded

export const utag = window.utag || { link: () => {}, view: () => {} };

// Usage: just use the exported utag, don't use the utag on window
utag.link({ ... })
```

### Wrap Utag Calls in a Promise

```
// If the utag call could possibly happen before utag has loaded (e.g. page load)
// This will make the call as soon as utag has loaded (it still drops it if utag doesn't load in a certain amount of time)

export const withUtag = async () => {
  if (window.utag) return window.utag;
  let i = 0;
  while (i < 50) {
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 200));
    if (window.utag) return window.utag;
    i = i + 1;
  }
  return { link: () => {}, view: () => {} };
}

// Usage: Use the resolved utag object from the Promise
withUtag().then(utag => utag.view({ ... }))
```

Comment: The 2 lines to modify the global script should be inside the <script> </script> right? Since we are adding that to the body of the page.

Comment: @TonyRoczz good catch!

Comment: Can you please update the answer, also can you share the link for a code repo with the above code just to get a better understanding on the over all implementation? Thanks

Comment: Life has been pretty hectic for me, but I have not forgotten this request.  When I have time I will double-back and try to create an example repo.

Comment: @TonyRoczz, I finally got around to making the example code repo: https://github.com/danielbank/react-tealium-example