# Tealium Tag Tracking with VueJs Nuxt

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, single-page-application, analytics, tealium

I am looking to implement Tealium Tags into my Nuxt.js application. I have tried working with the [documentation provided](https://docs.tealium.com/platforms/javascript/single-page-applications/) and some [StackOverflow answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56691221/tealium-tags-integration-with-react-js) and I am having trouble understanding where in the nuxt application all of the code goes? I have tried using the code as a service and as a static js file? Any help would be greatly appreciated I am stumped.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you write a minimal page component (perhaps a module for something more elaborate) into which you'd send any references to other elements on the page you want to track lifecycle events for.

Install the Tealium scripts on your page as you'd normally do (async script in your `<body>` tags and if you're using it, the synchronous script in your `<head>` tags). That has nothing to do with the Vue runtime, though you might have to edit your root template to install these.

Per the Tealium documentation you cited, you'd want to disable the automatic page tracking functionality. Instead, if you installed the Tealium async script properly, the `utag` object will be available on your window. After the new page has been mounted, kick off a call to `utag.view()` to trigger any pageview tags to execute.